# Wildfly 14 - explicit dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, wildfly, deployment-descriptor

I have two EAR (**ear01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear**, **ear02-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear**) applications and both of them are useing a common library (**common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**). I decided to move out that common part and add it as module to a **Wildfly 14** but even with a deployment descritor I get exception during the EAR deployment:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link ki/wildfly_deps/ejbs01/EchoBean01
```

I used this CLI to add the new module:

```
module add --name=ki.wildfly_deps.common --resources=common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and the JAR now is in

```
$JBOSS_HOME/modules/ki/wildfly_deps/common/main
```

**1. QUESTION**

This JAR shouldn't be in folder

```
$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/ki/wildfly_deps/common/main
```

beside the other modules?

After adding the module, the **module.xml** look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="ki.wildfly_deps.common">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

The **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** from each EAR declares a dependency on the above common library:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="ki.wildfly_deps.common" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

**2. QUESTION**

Should I specify the package what must be imported from the common module?

```
<jboss-deployment-structure
xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="ki.wildfly_deps.common" //>
            <imports>
                <include path="META-INF**" />
                <include path="ki.wildfly_deps.common**" />
            </imports>
        </module>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace?

Comment: As @JamesR.Perkins asked, what is full stacktrace? My suspicion is that problem is that your module needs to add some explicit dependencies to java modules.